# JDBC - automatically shrink VARCHAR to fit

Tags: mysql, jdbc, truncate

Got this exception:

```
Exception: Data truncation: Data too long for column 'subject' at row 1
```

This data is for display purposes so it's OK to truncate.

The easy thing to do is truncate in the logic - `subject = subject.subString(0, 100)` - but this will duplicate the max length in MySQL to the number I hardcode in the Java.  Is there a feature in any of MySQL or JDBC (I'm using c3p0 if that matters) that will truncate to fit automatically?

Answer (score 1):

> If strict SQL mode is not enabled and you assign a value to a CHAR or VARCHAR column that exceeds the column's maximum length, the value is truncated to fit and a warning is generated.

(from [The CHAR and VARCHAR Types](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/char.html))

If you don't mind changing the MySQL Server mode to not strict then no exception will be thrown.

See [Server Modes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-sql-mode.html)

Comment: Definitely don't want a global non-strict setting here.  If I could set this to just the column that would work but I'm guessing this isn't possible.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of hard coding 100, use the column property that defines the width.
You don't realy care how long it is in the db, just taht it doesn't blow up based on your client side length definition.

Comment: Can I do this in the SQL query itself?

Comment: This would be fine but I haven't successfully figured out how to query for a VARCHAR column width in my SQL.

Comment: Out of date on mysql, but something like Select from SysColumns or it's equivalent should get you close.

Answer (score 0):

Truncation on insertion is an Exception and drivers are required to throw an exception ([`DataTruncation`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/DataTruncation.html)); see section 8.3 of JDBC 4.1:

> When data truncation occurs on a write to the data source, a
>   DataTruncation object is thrown. The data value that has been truncated may
>   have been written to the data source even if a warning has been generated. When
>   data truncation occurs on a read from the data source, a SQLWarning is reported.

There is also silent truncation (using `setMaxFieldSize()` on a Statement, but the Javadoc only talks about the fields in a ResultSet, so it is unclear if that should also apply to parameters set on a PreparedStatement.